# Android ArrayAdapter/ListView does not update in Fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, android-arrayadapter

I am facing a problem while updating a ListView via an ArrayAdapter in a Android Fragment.

I have a method handling a .csv that is retrieved from a server. It parses the .csv and does the following:

```
for(int i =0; i< lines.length; i++){
    String[] words = lines[i].split(",");
        for(int j = 0;j<words.length; j++)
            if ( j%6 == 1 || j%6 == 2)
                getArrayAdapter().add(words[j]);
```

Using breakpoints, I can see that "words[j]" is a valid String. The method getArrayAdapter is the following:

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> getArrayAdapter(){
   if (aa == null){
        ListView lv = (ListView)   getCurrentActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getCurrentActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        aa.setNotifyOnChange(true);
        lv.setAdapter(aa);
    }
    return aa;
}
```

If the "getArrayAdapter().add(words[j]);" is called, method "notifyDataSetChanged()" in ArrayAdapter is called, as it should:

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mNotifyOnChange = true;
}
```

Via its parent it reaches DataBaseObservable that does this:

```
public void notifyChanged() {
    synchronized(mObservers) {
        // since onChanged() is implemented by the app, it could do anything, including
        // removing itself from {@link mObservers} - and that could cause problems if
        // an iterator is used on the ArrayList {@link mObservers}.
        // to avoid such problems, just march thru the list in the reverse order.
        for (int i = mObservers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            mObservers.get(i).onChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The array of observers had an "AdapterDataSetObserver" that contains all kind of references to my adapter and ListView. I looked what happens in the onChanged() of AdapterDataSetObserver, but I do not really know what to look at.

My table_fragment.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:id="@+id/top">
    <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dip"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:numColumns="2"
              android:columnWidth="30dp"
              android:id="@+id/list">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The xml of the activity containing the Fragment looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment android:name="com.example.TableFragment"
              android:id="@+id/table_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="0"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When looking in the log, nothing strange is there. All seems to go fine, but the screen does not show any of the strings.

What am I missing here? Probably missing something trivial, since I am a newbie to Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that layout_height of the ListView can be 0 (it auto expands). However, in the xml of the activity that contains the fragment, the layout_height could could not be set to 0 (it does not auto expand). I had put that on 0dip as well (after suggestion of Eclipse). Changing to "match_parent" did the job (despite the Eclipse warnings).

Answer (score 2):

```
android:layout_height="0dip"
```

this is wrong. You should let get the `ListView` all the available space. Change it in `fill_parent`

then:

```
aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getCurrentActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

you need to submit to the Apdater the dataset you want to show. For this purpose you  should use this [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20T%5B%5D%29)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I set the layout_height to "fill_parent" (later to "match_parent", since "fill_parent" seems deprecated) and changed the constructor (See edited question) by feeding it an ArrayList. Unfortunately, situation is not changed. 
PS: Reason for setting layout_height to 0 dip was a suggestion from eclipse that this would be more efficient.

Comment: you provide to the adapter an empty dataset. Are you aware thata dataset is used to fill up the ListView?

Comment: My understanding is that the add method of the adapter adds an item to the underlying dataset (provided in my case by the empty arraylist). In such case, the observer updates the ListView accordingly. Am I wrong here?

Comment: I am sorry. I have not noticed you used the add method. Are you subclassing the ArrayAdapter?

Comment: No, I do not. It is my plan to do so and I started with that. It did not work, so I decided to first get it up and running with the normal ArrayAdapter implementation.

Comment: when for(int i =0; i< lines.length; i++) ends, try calling aa.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I have tried that one before, and again after your suggestion, but to no result. Notification seems done, and aa.mObjects contains the arraylist that contains a lot of strings, but nothing is shown :(

Comment: I see. in your original adapter change  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 with  android.R.id.text1.

Comment: That did not do it, but it is solved now. It turns out that layout_height of the ListView can be 0 (it auto expands). However, in the xml of the activity that contains the fragment, the layout_height could could not be set to 0 (it does not auto expand). I put that on 0dip as well (after suggestion of eclipse).  Changing to "match_parent" did the job (and gives me Eclipse warnings). IMHO eclipse should not suggest it and the fragment should auto expand. Thanks for your hints blackbelt, really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

@Jos, the answer you selected is not the correct answer. The `ListView` height can, and should be, 0dp.  In order for the `ListView` to function in its default manner you need to change the Id of the `ListView` to exactly `android:id="@id/android:list"` and you can also add a `TextView` or `ProgressBar` to show when the list is empty, also the default function of `ListView`, something like the following:

```
<TextView
android:id="@id/android:empty"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:text="@+string/empty_list_message" />
```

Again the id must match exactly, everything else can change to suit your needs.
Here is what the complete xml would look like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" 
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/empty_list_message" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The `layout_weight` and `listSelector` are particular to my program, you may or may not need these.